# Bluetooth Headphones Microphone priority in Gnome on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, microphone, bluetooth-speaker

I'm using decent headphones with microphone (headset) and in general they're working find. No connectivity issues, sound is good. However,...

As they turn off themselves put away to conserve batteries I have recurring problem with microphone input settings. When I turn them on and they reconnect, the speaker output is set correctly, so I hear output straight away.

However, as I use the headset for work a lot I need to take part in meetings, the microphone is very important to me. But the system do not switch default input to microphone on reconnection. I have to manually go to **Settings** window into **Sound** section and switch microphone to my headset in **Input**. That's damn annoying flaw. Especially as if my docking station is connected, jack on it remains default input meaning one one hears me until I switch.

### Question

Is there any hidden setting to prioritize sound input devices, so headphones are make default when reconnect over Bluetooth? Somehow that works with output, why not with input?

I didn't have such issues on Windows. There I can even separate meeting devices from music devices, what Ubuntu (Linux in general?) is missing.